# Failed to retrieve data for this request SQL Server 2008 R2 Express SP2 Setup Issues

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, exception, installation

I am installing SQL Server 2008 R2 SP2 Express on a remote machine.

This is the exception error I get

> Exception summary:
>
> The following is an exception stack listing the exceptions in outermost to innermost order
>
> Inner exceptions are being indented
>
> Exception type: Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.EnumeratorException
>   Message: Failed to retrieve data for this request.
>   Data: HelpLink.ProdName = Microsoft SQL Server
>   HelpLink.BaseHelpUrl = http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink
>   HelpLink.LinkId = 20476
>   DisableWatson = true
>
> Stack: 
>               at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.Enumerator.Process(Object connectionInfo, Request request)
>               at Microsoft.SqlServer.Chainer.Infrastructure.SqlDiscoveryDatastoreInterface.ProcessDTbl(DataTable dt, Int32 level)
>               at Microsoft.SqlServer.Chainer.Infrastructure.SqlDiscoveryDatastoreInterface.CollectSqlDiscoveryData(String machineName)
>               at Microsoft.SqlServer.Chainer.Infrastructure.SqlDiscoveryDatastoreInterface.CollectDiscoveryData(String machineName)
>               at Microsoft.SqlServer.Chainer.Infrastructure.SqlDiscoveryDatastoreInterface.LoadData(IEnumerable`1 machineNames, String discoveryDocRootPath, String clusterDiscoveryDocRootPath)
>               at Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.SetupExtension.RunDiscoveryAction.ExecuteAction(String actionId)
>               at Microsoft.SqlServer.Chainer.Infrastructure.Action.Execute(String actionId, TextWriter errorStream)
>               at Microsoft.SqlServer.Setup.Chainer.Workflow.ActionInvocation.ExecuteActionHelper(TextWriter statusStream, ISequencedAction actionToRun)
>           Inner exception type: System.InvalidCastException
>               Message: 
>                       Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.String[]'.
>               Stack: 
>                       at Microsoft.SqlServer.Discovery.DiscoveryEnumObject.GetSql2kMsiInstanceListInHive(String machineName, RegistryView regView)
>                       at Microsoft.SqlServer.Discovery.DiscoveryEnumObject.LoadSql2kInstanceList(String machineName)
>                       at Microsoft.SqlServer.Discovery.Product.GetData(EnumResult erParent)
>                       at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.Environment.GetData()
>                       at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.Environment.GetData(Request req, Object ci)
>                       at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.Enumerator.GetData(Object connectionInfo, Request request)
>                       at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.Enumerator.Process(Object connectionInfo, Request request)

Has anyone experienced this problem? I've read many links and its referring to problems in Management Studio. But I haven't even installed SQL Server yet. Any help or advice would be appreciated.

Thanks